# How to add Compiler Argument in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm using Compose and some methods require the `@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)` annotation. 
The thing is that the Android Studio keeps showing a warning in this annotation with the following message: *This annotation should be used with the compiler argument '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'*. 
The code works normally but I would like to do what Android Studio suggests to remove this warning. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` from app module you can add the `freeCompilerArgs += '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'` inside `kotlinOptions` block. Like this:

```
plugins {
    // ...
}

android {
    // ...

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs += '-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn'
    }

    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
}
```